# Tag synonym: "gels" and "color-filters"?

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

Are [gels](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gels) and [color-filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-filters) synonyms?

If so I lack the rep to make that suggestion.  Could someone who does submit it?

Comment: Has there been a recent omnibus scrubbing of the tags? On this monitor, there are _31_ screens of tags, which just offhand seems way too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't gels the things you put on a flash to colour the light and colour-filters the ones you screw on a lens to warm/cool an image? So they're two distinct objects and I don't see why you would want to merge them.